# Database view in pyqt

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt

Is there an easy way to display the contents of a table from sqlite in pyqt? The only examples I can find are either in C++ or have relational tables.

Comment: Just for the record, for the most part (minus some api changes like qt's c++ enabled() method vs pyqt's isEnabled() method) you can map c++ code to the python equivalent. Just need to have knowledge of both languages and qt, but it's not that hard. (the answer by stephen is correct).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [QSqlTableModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsqltablemodel.html) class and pass it to a QTableView.  Assuming you have a QSqlDatabase object named `db`,

```
model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self, db)
model.setTable("YourTable")
model.select()

tableview = QtGui.QTableView()
tableview.setModel(model)
tableview.show()
```